# Drop down menu on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

I would like to create a drop down menu on top of my google maps, or a menu to the side of my google maps. This menu would have the options to select markers that are on the map and center the map around the selected marker. Does anyone know of any tutorials that show this, or how to do this?

Comment: did I misunderstand because the majority of the answers are talking about custom controls and I don't think thats what you were talking about. It seems only Pratik, got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for menu define div tag for menu. this menu set the postion as absolute and for that you need to set the left and top value. As you define the div as absolute that div you can display any where on the screen.

and your menu code put into this div so you can set your menu at anywhere on the screen

Answer (score 5):

You can find a working demo [here](http://vislab-ccom.unh.edu/~briana/examples/gdropdown/).
Check out the source code[CTRL + u] for impl. It's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Start here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomControls